# Resetting Mysql Auto increment Value Every year?

Tags: mysql

I have going with complaint management system. So the Case number was recorded yearly basis. 01/06/2016  here 01 is the ID that is auto increment value, 06 is month and 2016 is year. my need is in year 2017 the ID again starts from 1.

Comment: You have knowledge of triggers

Answer (score 0):

This is just logic part you need to deal with it.

```
SELECT CONCAT('0',IF(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('01/06/2016','/',-1)) = YEAR(NOW()),
(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX('01/06/2016','/',1))+1),1),'/',MONTH(NOW()),'/',YEAR(NOW()))
```